# Wires in BLTouch connector are loose, how to fold a crumpled pin

Tags: bltouch

I'm trying to install BLTouch on my Ender 3 Pro but I've been pulling the cables in and out so many times that crimp pins (I think that is what they are called, I mean the little metal bits crumpled on the end of the wire) are now almost completely loose and when I try to put the cable into the socket two of the cables are pushed out by pins in the board.

I've got a couple of uncrumpled header pins but I don't know how to bend them so that they clamp wires.

I've attached the part similar to what I have (I don't have a good enough phone to snap a photo of the original part I have).
[image: Plastic connectors and its pins]

Comment: Is the BLTouch the ANTCLABS brand? Is the image provided the same as the connector on your "BLTouch"?

Answer (score 1):

You need a crimping tool like this so that the pins will be crimped correctly to fix in the sockets and plugs.

[image]